# YouTube Data API: listLiveBroadcasts doesn't work... why?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I try to use the YouTube API, but when I wish to use the `LiveBroadcasts.list` API.
When I use the same JSON key to list my playlist it's OK... I don't understand why.

```php
$client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/../../key/youtube_client.json');
        $client->setApplicationName('Broadcast');
        $client->setScopes([
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
        ]);

$service = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    
$broadcastsResponse = $service->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts(
    'id,snippet,contentDetails',
    array(
        'broadcastType' => 'persistent',
        'mine' => 'true',
    )
);
```

The error message is:

> { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22), "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }

Can someone help me to know where is my mistake?

Comment: Please post the code creating the object `$client`.

Comment: Please edit your question and include all of your authorization code.

Comment: done, thanks for the tip

Comment: Please follow @DaImTo's request to post *all of your authorization code*. The part you've shown is OK, but you've not posted the code that runs the OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow. See this public Google sample code: [`list_broadcasts.php`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/list_broadcasts.php).

Comment: Ok thanks, but wiuth this process i can't use without manually login ... or i don't understand something

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a lot of the authorization code that is required in order to fetch an access token.

```
<?php

/**
 * Sample PHP code for youtube.liveBroadcasts.list
 * See instructions for running these code samples locally:
 * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#php
 */

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API code samples');
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);

// TODO: For this request to work, you must replace
//       "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json" with a pointer to your
//       client_secret.json file. For more information, see
//       https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys
$client->setAuthConfig('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// Request authorization from the user.
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print('Enter verification code: ');
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));



// Exchange authorization code for an access token.
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$response = $service->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts('');
print_r($response);
```

This sample is going to end up running more as a console application as it just builds the url for you.  If you need it run as a web application let me know i have some other sampes just not for this API which you can find [here](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples).  If you need help altering it let me know.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo but i have this error

Type: InvalidArgumentException
Message: missing the required redirect URI 

why ?

Comment: the user action is mandatory, isn't possible only with json key or other ?

Comment: The YouTube API doesn't support service accounts, so no there is no way around the user interaction. You need to verify it at least once.

Comment: Arfff ok, the user verification is needed manually ...

Comment: Hello Everybody,

I found a solution, i explain here

- logIn from my API with Google Client, and i store the access_token & refresh_token in cookie (will be secure because i'm the only one to connect my local Raspberry Pi)
- the access_token stored in cookie will be use by all call to https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/
- i use many endpoints to create brodcast, bind stream, check status of stream and stop de broadcast

The refresh_token are use for an automatic refresh (offline) while the broadcast are live, to keep the status up 

this solution is fully ok for my usage